# Method for Adaptive Cards with Variable Height Text in Sketch

Tags: symbols, overriding, sketch-3

Has anyone managed to pin down a method for creating cards in Sketch which will play well with adaptive height text overrides? For example, a simple card with a thumbnail, title and excerpt might have a title which is 1, 2 or 3 lines and an excerpt which is anything between 6 and 12+ lines. I'd like to know how to position the excerpt relative to the new height of the title but it seems not to interpret the new three-line height, only it's original height in the symbol. See attached for illustration.

[image]

Methods that I've tried include pinning the excerpt to the bottom but that doesn't play well with the variable length of the excerpt and grouping the title and the thumbnail. The only working method that I have is creating three instances of the symbol called post-title-one-line, post-title-two-line, post-title-three-line – which seems clunky.

Looking for any ideas or direction to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the [Auto-Layout by Anima](https://github.com/AnimaApp/Auto-Layout) plugin. Follow the [documentation](https://animaapp.github.io/docs/v1/auto-layout/) and examples provided to learn how to use it. Here's an example solution:

[Screenshot of Sketch File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc8tw.png)

[Example Sketch File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/at77busxfk4xoib/AutoLayout.sketch?dl=0)

Comment: Awesome, looks like that will do the trick. Thanks for taking the time to provide your example, @ayidi. I've been playing about with [Paddy](https://github.com/DWilliames/paddy-sketch-plugin) recently but it doesn't play well with text areas or with nested symbols  at this time. Auto Layout appears to handle all that.